# 2D Laplace equation using NDSolve and mixed boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve the laplace-equation in 2 dimensions, using mixed boundary conditions. The code I used is:

```
NDSolve[
{D[u[x, z], x, x] == -D[u[x, z], z, z],u[x, 10] == 0,
(D[u[x, z], z] /. z -> 10) == 0,u[x, 0] == SquareWave[x]},
 u, {x, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}]
```

The error messages I get are:

```
CoefficientArrays::poly: (u^(0,1))[x,10] is not a polynomial.

NDSolve::fembdnl: The dependent variable in (u^(0,1))[x,10]==0 
in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[(u^(0,1))[x,10]==0,z==10.] 
needs to be linear.
```

I don't know what's the problem, can you help me figure out this error messages?

Best regards

Thorsten

Comment: Your boundary condition is wrong. (You set 3 boundary conditions in `z` direction and 0 boundary condition in `x` direction.)

Answer (score 1):

You must write `u[x,z]` instead of `u` in NDSolve. Then the problem can be numerically solved.

However, as xzczd pointed out in a coment, the boundary conditions are not correct. With three b.c. in z-direction an None in x-direction the problem is ill-defined.

Nevertheless there is a numerical "solution", and due to numerical inaccuracy the violation of the second b.c. (the derivative) is not obvious.

Here is the numerical solution:

```
$Version

(* Out[298]= "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)" *)

uu[x_, z_] = 
 u[x, z] /. 
  NDSolve[{D[u[x, z], x, x] == -D[u[x, z], z, z], 
     u[x, 10] == 0, (D[u[x, z], z] /. z -> 10) == 0, 
     u[x, 0] == SquareWave[x]}, u[x, z], {x, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}][[1]]

(* Out[293]= InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}, {0., 10.}}, <>][x, z] *)

Plot3D[uu[x, z], {x, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, 
 ViewPoint -> {\[Pi], \[Pi]/2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, z, u}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well...  but how can one set 3 b.c. for one direction when solving Laplace equation?

Comment: @xzczd Good question. You are right. In my opinion it is a numerical effect that you are allowed to gives 3 b.c. Try varying the derivative (D[u[x, z], z] /. z -> 10) == d. You can go as high as d = 20 without altering the picture. This b.c. is by no means matched. So one should be careful appreciating nice pictures.

Comment: @xzczd Please see the updated version of my solution.

Comment: I even guess in v10.1 that b.c. is simply ignored. Just tested on Cloud, though using 3 b.c. will cause failure in v11, if the condition `D[u[x, z], z] /. z -> 10) == 0` is taken away, a plot that just looks the same as the above one will be generated.