# Non-linear Poisson equation over non-rectangular domain

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I need to solve non-linear Poisson equation

`Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == u[x, y]^2`

Over a non-rectangular domain

The problem in short: non-linear Poisson equation over rectangular domain runs OK, and linear Poisson equation over non-rectangular domain runs OK, but not the non-linear over non-rectangular.

The domain is

```
boundaries = {-y, .25^2 - (x)^2 - y^2, -x, y - 1, x - 1};

\[CapitalOmega]in = 
ImplicitRegion[And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ boundaries), {x, y}];

Show[RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]in], 
ContourPlot[
Evaluate[Thread[boundaries == 0]], {x, 0., 1}, {y, 0, 1.}, 
ContourStyle -> {Purple, Green, Red, Blue, Purple}], 
PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1}, {0., 1.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

with simple boundary conditions

```
  Conditions = {DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, 
  boundaries[[1]] == 0.],
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[2]] == 0],
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[3]] == 0.],
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[4]] == 0.],
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[5]] == 0.],
  u[0, x, y] == 1};
```

I try to run a relaxation scheme

```
 Eq = Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - u[t, x, y]^2

sol = NDSolveValue[{Eq == Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], 
Conditions}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "Automatic", 
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]
```

The problem is "Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve".

The linear Poisson equation runs OK

```
Eq = Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - u[t, x, y]

sol = NDSolveValue[{Eq == Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], 
 Conditions}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "Automatic", 
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]

ContourPlot[sol[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 50, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Also, non-linear over a rectangular domain runs OK:

```
boundaries = {-y, -x, y - 1, x - 1};
\[CapitalOmega]in = 
ImplicitRegion[And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ boundaries), {x, y}];

 Show[RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]in], 
 ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Thread[boundaries == 0]], {x, 0., 1}, {y, 0, 1.}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Purple, Green, Red, Blue, Purple}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1}, {0., 1.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic] 

Conditions = {DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, 
 boundaries[[1]] == 0.],
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[2]] == 0],
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[3]] == 0.],
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[4]] == 0.],
 u[0, x, y] == 1};

 sol = NDSolveValue[{Eq == Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], 
  Conditions}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "Automatic", 
 "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]

 ContourPlot[sol[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 50, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Your last block of code doesn't work. I guess it's because you have changed the definiton of  `Conditions` . It works fine with `Conditions = {u[t, 0, y] == 1,u[t, 1, y] == 1,u[t, x, 0] == 1,u[t, x, 1] == 1,u[0, x, y] == 1};`. Please correct your question.

Comment: @andre - yes the boundaries and Conditions are a bit different in the last block from the previous - there 4 boundaries and 4 Conditions (not 5 like before).  I think your and mine are identical. If you run the last block as a whole it works OK.

Comment: I have posted a [question related to your problem (very likely)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/5467)

Comment: Mac, Mathematica 10.2.0.0

Comment: It's Strange. I haved tried my code below on the cloud (Wolfram Development Paltform, Mathematica 11.1 Unix). It doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you evaluate `sol["ElementMesh"]` in both cases (the one that works and the one that doesn't work). If you want to know why, see the link in the comment above)

Comment: I must leave. Here is what's probably happening : The finite element method only accepts linear PDEs. The other Method, (ProductTensorGrid) accepts your non-linear PDE. But ProductTensorGrid only accept rectangular domain.To be confirmed.

Comment: I tried sol["ElementMesh"] for three cases:

(i) Non-linear Poisson, rectangular box: None.

(ii) Linear Poisson, non-rectangular box: NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh[{{0., 1.}, {0.,  1.}}, {NDSolve`FEM`TriangleElement["<" 502 ">"]}]

(iii) Non-linear Poisson, non-rectangular box: just a repetition of the  NDSolve command. 

You guess about how different methods handle non-linearities sounds right. But is there a way around? - To solve the non-linear problem on non-rectangular box?

Comment: "non-linear over a rectangular domain runs OK" It should not be OK, because `NDSolve` simply can't handle it properly, see the comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139348/1871) for more information. If _v10.2_ really gives a solution in that case, I guess it's because its instability. (We know _v10_ is unstable for a long time. ) Something similar happened before: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129314/1871 @andre

Comment: If you really want to solve the nonlinear equation on an irregular domain, start from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/1871). (It's not that easy, I admit.)

Comment: @MaximLyutikov, you looking for the stationary (non time dependent) solution to your non-linear PDE or the time dependent solution?

Comment: It seem @user21 provided the solution, see below.  Also, after updating to Mathematica 11.1.0.0 the non-linear problem over the rectangular domain stopped working.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the stationary solution of the non-linear PDE over a region. Unfortunately, `NDSolve` can not handle this out of the box (V11.1) but you can use the low-level FEM functions to get a solution. To do so we roughly follow the idea presented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/18437). The idea is to create an interpolating function in every non-linear step and feed that into the linearized coefficients.

Setup: We use a linear Laplace equation, so get the linear discretization:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
\[CapitalOmega]in = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ {-y, .25^2 - (x)^2 - y^2, -x, y - 1, 
       x - 1}), {x, y}];
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
conditions = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, True]};
```

`ProcessPDEEquations` is a build in function (V11. in NDSolveFEM context) that does the same as the `PDEtoMatrix` function in the [linked code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/18437).

```
{dPDE, dBC, vd, sd, md} = 
  ProcessPDEEquations[{op, conditions}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False}}];

mesh2 = md["ElementMesh"];
linearLoad = dPDE["LoadVector"];
linearStiffness = dPDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
diriPos = dBC["DirichletRows"];
```

Now, we can start to write the non-linear loop. This version is a little different to the version in the other post. Mainly, how it handles boundary conditions.

The `InitializedPDECoefficients` gets the linearized coefficients at `uOld`. Finding this linearization is the hardest part. For those I'd like to refer you to [Wolfgang Bangerth's Video lectures](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/videos.676.31.5.html).

```
ClearAll[rhs]
rhs[uIn_] := Module[{uOld}, uOld = uIn;
  Do[ClearAll[u0];
   u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh2}, uOld];
   nlPdeCoeff = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd
     , "LoadCoefficients" -> {
       {-u0[x, y]^2}
       }
     , "LoadDerivativeCoefficients" -> {
       {{-Derivative[1, 0][u0][x, y], -Derivative[0, 1][u0][x, y]}}
       }
     , "ReactionCoefficients" -> {
       {2 u0[x, y]}
       }
     ];
   nlsys = DiscretizePDE[nlPdeCoeff, md, sd];
   nlLoad = nlsys["LoadVector"];
   nlStiffness = nlsys["StiffnessMatrix"];
   ns = nlStiffness + linearStiffness;
   nl = nlLoad + linearLoad;

   nl[[diriPos]] = {0.};
   ns[[diriPos, All]] = 0.;
   ns[[All, diriPos]] = 0.;
   (ns[[#, #]] = 1.) & /@ diriPos;

   dU = LinearSolve[ns, nl];
   Print[i, " Residual: ", Norm[nl, Infinity], "  Correction: ", 
    Norm[dU, Infinity]];
   uOld = uOld + dU;
   , {i, 8}];
  uOld]
```

Another word on boundary conditions. In this version of the non-linear loop the initial guess has to satisfy the boundary conditions. Because the `uOld` satisfies the boundary conditions we modify the load vector and (tangent) stiffness matrix such that `uOld = uOld + du` will still respect the boundary conditions. (Again this is explained in the video lectures)

We setup the initial guess and set the boundary conditions:

```
guess = 1.;
uOld = ConstantArray[{guess}, md["DegreesOfFreedom"]];
uOld[[diriPos]] = dBC["DirichletValues"];
```

We run the code:

```
uNew = rhs[uOld];

1 Residual: 0.0016115  Correction: 0.0637695
2 Residual: 5.34982*10^-6  Correction: 0.000162486
3 Residual: 3.45194*10^-11  Correction: 8.79701*10^-10
4 Residual: 4.94049*10^-15  Correction: 1.27027*10^-15
5 Residual: 2.65066*10^-15  Correction: 1.02935*10^-15
6 Residual: 2.84928*10^-15  Correction: 1.21563*10^-15
7 Residual: 3.17975*10^-15  Correction: 1.16816*10^-15
8 Residual: 2.75214*10^-15  Correction: 1.10233*10^-15
```

We have quadratic convergence. (That will change if you omit the `"ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> False` - then region will be approximated better but the interpolation of the `uOld` on curved leads to some damping(?))

Well, the plot:

```
eif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{md["ElementMesh"]}, uNew];
Plot3D[eif[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I am adapting your code to my problem  - how do I modify 
 guess = 1.;
to more complicated boundary conditions with more complicated Dirichlet conditions and some Neumann?

Comment: This line `uOld[[diriPos]] = dBC["DirichletValues"];` is setting the boundary conditions to what you have. `guess=1` is to the the initial guess inside the domain. - With the NeumannValue I don't know. You should create an example to which you know the solution and experiment (and tell me ;-)

Comment: My actual boundary conditions look something like that:

 boundaries = {-y, 0.25^2 - (x)^2 - y^2, -x, y - 1, x - 1};

 op = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
     NeumannValue[0, boundaries[[1]] == 0.] + 
     NeumannValue[0, boundaries[[5]] == 0.] == 0;

 conditions = {
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, boundaries[[4]] == 0.], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, boundaries[[3]] == 0.],
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1/(1 + x), boundaries[[2]] == 0.]};

I would like generate  'guess'     array to be consistent with that. How would I do that?

Comment: You can ignore the Neumann 0. The code should work as is else I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @MaximLyutikov, could you figure this out?

Comment: the code runs well. I think I need one last hint: In the initial simple form of my question, the non-linear part was just u[x,y]^2. In fact, what I have is a numerical function F[u] - a given function of the solution, not of coordinates. Previous case F[u]=u^2 was just a simple example. How to modify the rhs  block in your code, so that it will take an InterpolationFunction for F[u], not analytical?

Comment: @MaximLyutikov, can you please update your question to contain the `InterpolatingFunction`? Do you also have a derivative of that function?

Comment: The non-linear right hand side in my case is a numerical function. Here I create InterpolationFunction Frhs[x] and its derivative with respect to the argument. At this point I arbitrarily chose ~ (x^2) 
   FofI = Interpolation[Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -100, 100, .1}]];
        Frhs[Z_] := FofI[Z]
 FReacCoef[Z_] := FofI'[Z]  
I think the only modification needed is in nlPdeCoeff: 

       "LoadCoefficients" -> {{-Frhs[u0[x, y]] }}, 
       "ReactionCoefficients" -> {{FReacCoef[ u0[x, y]]}}];

Comment: Could be correct. I mean have you tried it - what comes out. I'd expect a convergence down to 10^-8 (because using an interpolating function will effect this) what do you see?

Comment: Yes, I do see good convergence for simple test cases. But not yet for my real problem -  still trying. Now, when I do search on wolfram.com, many of commands that you use in that rhs block you wrote for me are not even found, like ProcessPDEEquations. For example, which exactly iterations algorithm did you use?

Comment: would you be interested in co-authoring a paper. The problem deals with magnetospheric structure of neutron stars - your contribution was essential.

Comment: @MaximLyutikov, for `ProcessPDEEquations` see updated post. Thanks for the generous offer to co-author. Even though it sounds very interesting I have other obligations - if you think my contribution was substantial you can add me in the acknowledgement section; I'd be interested to read the paper though. (ruebenko AT wolfram.com). Good luck.

Comment: OK. How would one modify the initial "guess" array to satisfy more complicated boundary conditions, both of Dirichlet and (non-zero) Neumann?

Comment: @MaximLyutikov for the Dirichlet case you can use the mesh. `Function[{X}, Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = X; x^2 + Sin[y]]] /@  mesh2["Coordinates"]`. For non-zero `NeumannValues` one would need a little more thought. Perhaps you update you question a bit with the relevant new questions you asked in the comments section.

Comment: good hint about the mesh, works better, still not there completely.

Comment: I think I need your help. I am not sure how you use InitializePDECoefficients - why there is "ReactionCoefficients" -> {{2 u0[x, y]}} for a basic Laplacian? How would this scheme look in cylindrical coordinates with no \phi-dependence? (For an equation u''_{rr} +u'_{r}/r + u''_{zz}==f[u].)

Comment: Because, `D[u[x, y]^2, u[x, y]]` is `2 u[x,y]`. Did you have a look at the video lectures I mentioned? [Chapter 4.2.4](https://www.freidok.uni-freiburg.de/fedora/objects/freidok:6440/datastreams/FILE1/content) may be useful.

Comment: how would the scheme look in cylindrical coordinates? I am trying to use "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{1/x ,0}}}, but it behaves really badly at not so small x.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{1/x ,0}}}. Please ask a new question as this has deviated quite a bit from this, the original question.

Comment: For the equation Laplacian[f[x,y]]=f^2[x,y] in Cartesian, the recursive scheme is 


 "LoadCoefficients" -> {
       {-u0[x, y]^2}
       }
     , "LoadDerivativeCoefficients" -> {
       {{-Derivative[1, 0][u0][x, y], -Derivative[0, 1][u0][x, y]}}
       }
     , "ReactionCoefficients" -> {
       {2 u0[x, y]}

.
How would it look for Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this linearization method would not work in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: the project moves ahead slowly. I have one more complication: on half of one of the boundaries, eg. {y==0, x<=1/2} I have Dirichlet conditions, while on the same boundary, but   {y==0, x>=1/2} I have zero Neumann. How to modify your code in this case?

Answer (score 4):

In version 12.0 this works out of the box:

```
boundaries = {-y, .25^2 - (x)^2 - y^2, -x, y - 1, x - 1};
\[CapitalOmega]in = 
  ImplicitRegion[And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ boundaries), {x, y}];
Conditions = {DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, 
    boundaries[[1]] == 0.], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[2]] == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[3]] == 0.], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[4]] == 0.], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[5]] == 0.], 
   u[0, x, y] == 1};
```

Nonlinear equation:

```
Eq = Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - u[t, x, y]^2;
```

Solve:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{Eq == Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], 
   Conditions}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in]
```

Plots:

```
ContourPlot[sol[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 50, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[sol[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer

I don't undestand your last comment.
If I take your last block of code with the addition of the missing definition `Eq = Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - u[t, x, y]^2`, it doesn't work on my machine (Mma 11.0.0.0 , Windows 7) . The first error message is :

> NDSolveValue::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported
>   in this version of NDSolve.

Here is the whole code :

```
Eq = Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - u[t, x, y]^2

boundaries = {-y, -x, y - 1, x - 1};
\[CapitalOmega]in = 
ImplicitRegion[And @@ (# <= 0 & /@ boundaries), {x, y}];

 Show[RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]in], 
 ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Thread[boundaries == 0]], {x, 0., 1}, {y, 0, 1.}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Purple, Green, Red, Blue, Purple}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1}, {0., 1.}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic] 

Conditions = {DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, 
 boundaries[[1]] == 0.],
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[2]] == 0],
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[3]] == 0.],
 DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 1, boundaries[[4]] == 0.],
 u[0, x, y] == 1};

 sol = NDSolveValue[{Eq == Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y], 
  Conditions}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "Automatic", 
 "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]

 ContourPlot[sol[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]in, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> 50, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: on my machine (Mac, Mathematica 10.2.0.0) both my and your code work OK, but only for rectangular grid. Yes, the general problem is the non-linearity.